# Is it more useful to study lots of methods/theorems or work with details?

Tags: soft-question, learning

Suppose one has to learn a new subject on book that contains hundreds of pages and hundreds of problems. Is it more useful to learn book by reading it and skipping those parts I don't understand and come back later to the hard parts, or read the book line by line and doing all exercises rigorously before moving to next page, possible by asking the details in this site?

Comment: I would at least read every proofs in details. Not all of them are useful but very often they contains the ingredients for solving the exercises (that you can do or not...). It also probably depends on the level of the book. If it a "starting" book then doing everything sounds responsible, if it is a specialized book then it is different.